# docker networking - Could not discover any bindable network interfaces

Tags: linux, macos, networking, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to execute a jar from within a docker container which tries to start a service and detects an IP and port of a remote service and tries to connect to it. But as soon as I do that I get this exception -

```
Exception occured: org.teleal.cling.transport.spi.InitializationException: Could not discover any bindable network interfaces and/or addresses
org.teleal.cling.transport.spi.InitializationException: Could not discover any bindable network interfaces and/or addresses
    at org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.NetworkAddressFactoryImpl.<init>(NetworkAddressFactoryImpl.java:99)
    at org.teleal.cling.DefaultUpnpServiceConfiguration.createNetworkAddressFactory(DefaultUpnpServiceConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.teleal.cling.DefaultUpnpServiceConfiguration.createNetworkAddressFactory(DefaultUpnpServiceConfiguration.java:220)
    at org.teleal.cling.transport.RouterImpl.<init>(RouterImpl.java:93)
    at org.teleal.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.createRouter(UpnpServiceImpl.java:97)
    at org.teleal.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:81)
    at org.teleal.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:58)
```

I tried to run the container with the --privileged flag as well so that I could get all the possible networking capabilities but it still threw the same exception.

I am running a boot2docker VM on my MAC OS X , where I am running this docker container.

On doing an ip addr within my docker container, I get this -

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether abcd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.90/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:5a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Would anyone have suggestions to get this service up and running ? I think the issue is with the docker networking here since I am able to run the same service on a native linux VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using the --net host flag which essentially says that i am going to use to your host's networking and in this case ip addr displays the host's machine networking eth0, eth1 details.

```
docker run -it --net host <image name> /bin/bash
```